# FLVPlayback not showing skin on exe

Tags: flash-cs4

I have a problem exporting a flash exe which contains flvplayback with external skin file.
Works fine on swf but on exe, it's not showing the skin controls
I am using Flash CS4.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that, as you said in your question, the skin used by Flash CS4 is stored in an external file.

You just have to put the skin file (SteelExternalPlaySeekMute.swf for instance) in the same directory than your .exe file, and it will work (just tested right now).

Comment: I double checked, the skin is in the same directory.